# Netsuite PHP Toolkit - Limit returned fields in Saved Search

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm working on an integration for Netsuite. When I return my saved search, there are 300+ fields returned for the `searchRowBasic` property. I'll include a var_dump below.

My source code is from Magento 2, so the factory methods are out of scope, but you can assume they create a new instance of the class (which i'll note).

I'm also using the [composer package for netsuite](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php) to utilize namespaces rather than Netsuite's official package that is one file with 1600 classes and no namespaces (seriously).

```
/** @var Netsuite\Classes\ItemSearchAdvanced $searchRecord */
$searchRecord = $this->itemSearchAdvancedFactory->create();
/** @var Netsuite\Classes\SearchRow $searchRow */
$searchRow = $this->itemSearchRowFactory->create();
/** @var Netsuite\Classes\SearchRowBasic $searchRowBasic */
$searchRowBasic = $this->itemSearchRowBasicFactory->create();

/** @var Netsuite\Classes\SearchRequest */
$request = $this->searchRequestFactory->create();
$searchRecord->savedSearchId = 190;
$request->searchRecord = $searchRecord;

/** @var Netsuite\NetsuiteService $netsuiteService */
// Loaded with authentication values.
$netsuiteService = $this->getNetsuiteService();
$netsuiteService->setSearchPreferences(false, 1000);

// Submit the request - returns successful response.
$searchResponse = $netsuiteService->search($request);
```

My Request returns a successful response (:thumbsup:)

The problem is that I want to use 4 variables in the entire response, but there are hundreds of indexes in the array that are unused. My biggest concern is that Netsuite is querying these during the response, my secondary concern is returning multiple KB's of data that I won't use within my response for larger requests.

I have tried this, to unset the parameters, hoping that if I undeclared them, Netsuite would ignore them in the response, but I had no luck.

```
protected function getSearchRecord(): ItemSearchAdvanced
{
    $searchRecord = $this->itemSearchAdvancedFactory->create();
    $searchRow = $this->itemSearchRowFactory->create();
    $searchRowBasic = $this->itemSearchRowBasicFactory->create();

    $i = 0;
    $fields = $searchRowBasic::$paramtypesmap;
    foreach ($fields as $name => $type) {
        // use only the first 10 just to see if only these 10 will be used. 
        // no such luck.
        if ($i > 10) {
            unset($searchRowBasic::$paramtypesmap[$name]);
            unset($searchRowBasic->$name);
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $searchRow->basic = $searchRowBasic;
    $searchRecord->columns = $searchRow;

    return $searchRecord;
}
```

### Question:

I know the fields I want to return before I make the request. How can I specify those fields to only return the data I need, not all the data available?

Here is a var_dump of the response to see the format. I truncated the data a good amount, if anyone needs more I can easily provide it, but I think there is enough info provided currently.

```
class NetSuite\Classes\SearchResponse#2452 (1) {
    public $searchResult =>
    class NetSuite\Classes\SearchResult#2449 (8) {
        public $status =>
        class NetSuite\Classes\Status#2447 (2) {
        public $statusDetail =>
        NULL
        public $isSuccess =>
        bool(true)
        }
        public $totalRecords =>
        int(1)
        public $pageSize =>
        int(1000)
        public $totalPages =>
        int(1)
        public $pageIndex =>
        int(1)
        public $searchId =>
        string(60) "<requst_id_with_personal_data>"
        public $recordList =>
        NULL
        public $searchRowList =>
        class NetSuite\Classes\SearchRowList#2475 (1) {
        public $searchRow =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            class NetSuite\Classes\ItemSearchRow#2476 (23) {
            public $basic =>
            class NetSuite\Classes\ItemSearchRowBasic#2477 (322) {
                public $accBookRevRecForecastRule =>
                NULL
                public $accountingBook =>
                NULL
                public $accountingBookAmortization =>
                NULL
                public $accountingBookCreatePlansOn =>
                NULL
                public $accountingBookRevRecRule =>
                NULL
                public $accountingBookRevRecSchedule =>
                NULL
                public $allowedShippingMethod =>
                NULL
                public $alternateDemandSourceItem =>
                NULL
                public $assetAccount =>
                NULL
                public $atpLeadTime =>
                NULL

                (more elements)...
            }
            public $assemblyItemBillOfMaterialsJoin =>
            NULL
            public $binNumberJoin =>
            NULL
            public $binOnHandJoin =>
            NULL
            public $correlatedItemJoin =>
            NULL
            public $effectiveRevisionJoin =>
            NULL
            public $fileJoin =>
            NULL
            public $inventoryDetailJoin =>
            NULL
            public $inventoryLocationJoin =>
            NULL
            public $inventoryNumberJoin =>
            NULL

            (more elements)...
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the XML response from the server, it looks like Netsuite was responding with only the columns declared in my saved search as I wanted. The other null values I was receiving were initialized as default values when the response object was initialized.